# scientific calculation in PHP

Tags: php, scientific-computing

i have a client that wants to turn this calculation into a function in PHP. i been given test numbers with an answer for it and i am out from this answer by too much for it to be correct im not sure if the calculation is wrong or im just not seeing the issue.

[image: Scientific Calculation]

```
function Density($m1 , $m2, $m3, $pw, $psm){

  return   $m1 /  (($m2 - $m3) / $pw) - (($m2 - $m1) / $psm) ; 
} 
$Density = ( Density(746.2, 761.7, 394.6, (998.1*1000), (761.7-746.2)) / 1000000)

output : 2.02882553228
answer : 2.127
```

also i have tried it like this as well but this is way far out for it to be right

```
function Density($m1 , $m2, $m3, $pw, $psm){

  return   $m1 /  ((($m2 - $m3) / $pw) - (($m2 - $m1) / $psm )); 
} 

output : -0.001
answer : 2.127
```

i know it should be as close to the answer as it can get 0.010 out fromthe correct answer but i dont see what im doing wrong please help internet.

Comment: What have you done so far to write it out?

Comment: That code with those inputs doesn't produce 2.02, from where do you get that? http://codepad.org/UjwiUylq

Answer (score 3):

Remember BEDMAS - brackets exponents division multiplication addition subtraction. Your code is wrong for the order-of-operations:

```
m1 / (((m2 - m3) / pw) - ((m2 - m1) / psm))
```

or, if that equation had been typeset properly:

```
          m1
 --------------------
 m2 - m3      m2 - m1
 -------  -   -------
    pw          psm
```

Comment: needs to be set to equal an output var somehow.

Comment: That being said, Their expectation of the result with these inputs is also wrong. Even this correct code does not produce 2.127. It does `-0.0007464746`. Either the formula is wrong or the output they expect is wrong still.

Comment: i know that somewhere this is wrong but this is the correct formula for the answer and that answer is suppose to be correct too as the test numbers are off a test certificate that is valid.

Comment: the either your posted equation picture is wrong, or the test certification is wrong. the above formula is correct as per the picture, **IF** standard BEDMAS rules are being observed.

Comment: i have no reason to doupt that the formula is wrong as this is a standardized formula that needs to be used as set by UKAS the board of the UK's Labratory Testing as well as every other country's testing agencies.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is different from the required.

You should ensure operator precedence rule is correctely observed:

```
return   $m1 /  ((($m2 - $m3) / $pw) - (($m2 - $m1) / $psm)) ;
```

Comment: this is the one i have tried and the output is -0.001 which is wrong